# Wrapper for an encapsulated function

Tags: python, wrapper, python-decorators

Lets say self.sigma is a float number and I define a function that returns a function a.

```
def f(self):
    a = lambda i: self.sigma*i**2
return a
```

Now I want to extend the functionality of a, whenever self.sigma is a matrix:

```
self.sigma = sigma[i,j]
```

where sigma is a 2-dimensional numpy array.

Is possible to define a wrapper to do it?
I would like something like:

```
def f(self):
    a = lambda i,j: self.sigma[i,j]*i**2
return a
```

without re-wrtting it explicitly. Is it the best way to do it?

Additional information:
In my programme f returns five functions not one. In the context of the program makes sense to encapsulate all this functions in a single function f.

Comment: Would a switch/case statement that checks the type of `self.sigma` with `type()` and changes the lambda it returns depending on it answer your question? If not, I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "not wanting to rewrite it explicitly", and what "it" is referring to

Comment: yes, indeed. But I was trying to find another walk around. I would not like to writte a single line of code inside f. Thats why I thought that a decorator might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [np.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) does something similar?

vectorizing f will return a matrix of lambdas. Each takes i as an input.

```py
import numpy as np

def f(sigma):
    a = lambda i: sigma*i**2
    return a

f_vectorized = np.vectorize(f)
sigma = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]

for i in [0, 1, 2]:
    for j in [0, 1]:
        print(f_vectorized(sigma)[i, j](i))

# prints 0, 0, 2, 3, 16, 20
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `sigma` is a numpy array your `f` works as expected:

```
import numpy as np

def f(sigma):
    a = lambda i: sigma*i**2
    return a

sigma = np.random.rand(2, 4)

print(sigma)
print(f(sigma)(2))

# [[0.40567906 0.86706289 0.37468664 0.45059327]
#  [0.57024244 0.17452584 0.05394594 0.03218902]]

# [[1.62271624 3.46825154 1.49874657 1.80237307]
#  [2.28096976 0.69810334 0.21578375 0.12875607]]
```

If your `sigma` is a list of lists, then you can use [vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) from numpy and get the array of functions:

```
sigma = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
vfunc = np.vectorize(f)

print(vfunc(sigma))
#[[<function f.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002DC116DE7B8>
#  <function f.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002DC116DEC80>]
#
# [<function f.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002DC116DEBF8>
# <function f.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002DC116DE730>]]
```

Comment: print(f(sigma)(2)) returns an array and should return a single number.

Comment: @FedericoVega why it should return a single number? You are passing an array - you get an array. You passing a single value - you get a single value.

Comment: Sorry you are right, It is just a matter to add some [i,j] to obtain the scalar. Thanks!